# Unable to get Current Location Using Jquery-ui-map v3 on IBM Worklight

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using jquery-ui-map V3 plugin for a map module in Worklight app. My code works in Mobile Browser Simulator. But when I try to run it in android device then I am unable to get location. Internet on Device is working also GPS is turned on. I have also added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in Android manifest file. 
Here is the code:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Ambit/nearestLocation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map.services.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map.overlays.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>
    </head>
```

**nearestLocation.js:**

```
$('#FindATM').live("pageshow", function () {
  $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function () {
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {

         if ( status === 'OK' ) {   
                var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition, 'bounds': true,'zoom': 11});
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Circle', { 
                    'strokeWeight': 0, 
                    'fillColor': "#008595", 
                    'fillOpacity': 0.25, 
                    'center': clientPosition, 
                    'radius': 10, 
                    'clickable': true

                });

        alert("If block is not executed on Android device. It does on Mobile Browser simulator");
               }


                  });
                 });
               });
```

Answer (score 1):

When using web based maps on Android, in the past, I've found I need to add to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
```

Also need to enable on the device or avd image GPS satellites and Location Services.

There maybe more refine approach, but this work last time I had to get it working.

Comment: Thanks eborysko. I have added these permissions but still no positive results !!.

Comment: Which device / network are you using? I've had issues with S3 devices and Verizon before. They have additional network options to enable GPS services on the device. I think they taking extra steps to protect battery life.@AbdulHannan

Comment: I am using HTC One X. I am  using WIFI and all GPS options are turned on. The built-in Maps app and my other native android apps are working fine.